# How do I give my text the same height as it's container?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="bigcontainer">
    <div class="container">
      <div>hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
.bigcontainer {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
} 

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However, as my website is responsive, I would like the text "hello" to always have the same height as its parent container. How can I achieve this using CSS?

Comment: You define the height of the `.bigcontainer` as 20%; is that 20% of the height of the page or an ancestor element? Also, incidentally, you have a syntax error in your code, the two adjacent quote characters before the word 'container': `class=""container"` is, obviously, wrong. Remove the duplicate to give: `"class="container"`.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container/19814948#19814948

Comment: @ni3solanki | Clearly, my question is targeting the height where as the other question targets the width. It's in the title...

Comment: @DavidThomas | Sorry, I was on my phone, I didn't notice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height of the html,body element to 100%
or You need to give the container a fixed value(bigcontainer).

To make the text same height as it's container(bigcontainer).  Get the container `offsetHeight` using javascript and assign it to the text as `height` and  `fontSize`

I have added **two** **container (bigcontainer)  heights**, one being **20%** and the other **50%**, so that the **text height and text size** **changes**.

Also i have added `border:1px solid black` to indicate the **`text height`**

1. if you need only text height remove `y.style.fontSize=x+'px'` and `yy.style.fontSize=xx+'px'`
2. if you need only text size (fontSize) remove `y.style.height=x+'px'` and `yy.style.height=xx+'px'`

Check the following examples

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].offsetHeight;
var y = document.getElementById('idname');
y.style.fontSize=x+'px';
y.style.height=x+'px';

var xx = document.getElementsByClassName('container2')[0].offsetHeight;
var yy = document.getElementById('idname2');
yy.style.fontSize=xx+'px';
yy.style.height=xx+'px';
```

```css
body,html {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.bigcontainer {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
} 
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.container div{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;

}

.bigcontainer2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
} 
.container2 {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}
.container2 div{
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<div class="bigcontainer">
    <div class="container">
      <div id='idname'>hello</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bigcontainer2">
    <div class="container2">
      <div id='idname2'>hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The vh is what you are looking for. Using the height as reference for the font-size is probably no problem for a short word as 'Hello' but if the word is longer then the word will wrap to the next line.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.bigcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;
} 
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 2vh;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15vh;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: I probably should've mentioned that `%` was needed.